# USER32 SetWindowPos hiding cursor

Tags: c#, console-application, user32

I'm trying from my console application to **position the window** itself with SetWindowPos and it works, but **the blinking cursor disappears**. How can I avoid it?

```
const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);

public static void SetWindowPosition(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), IntPtr.Zero, x, y, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}

void run()
{
   SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 300, 300);
}
```

Comment: Are you focused in console window?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: hmm it is working on me

Comment: Can you check with Console.CursorVisible?

Comment: Console.CursorVisible is true

Comment: Probably you console window is not activated. Try to "click" in your console window when it moves. If the blinking cursor appears then window no activated

Comment: unfortunately even if I try to move the window or click inside the cursor it is hidden

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.windowleft?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I believe WindowLeft has another purpose

Comment: Please try the properties linked by Hans and tell us how they differ from your expected outcome.